# Which kernel 'api' does nouveau driver uses?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

I'm trying to read the nouveau source code: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau

Normally, a driver will register itself as something. For example, a USB driver will register itself as a USB device. A keyboard driver as an HiD device.

I'm trying to understand how nouveau driver works (simply because it's an open source driver and I'd like to learn more about the kernel)

Which Linux kernel "api" does the nouveau kernel driver use?

Comment: It surely uses at least ACPI and PCI[e].

Comment: The display manager is not part of the kernel